# Add Html element into listview

Tags: c#, html, winforms

I have snippet of code that need to be added into control, I am trying to add it into listview but html element doesn't appear as item.

is there any good control that can display html elements

Comment: Do you have an example of what you have tried ?

Comment: You can't use HTML in winforms. Do you mean webforms? Can we have more information and see some code you have tried?

Comment: Nothing but the WebBrowser control.